# Are ripped mp4's from original cd with iTunes protected with my iTunes account password?

Tags: itunes, compact-disc, ripping

When I rip an original CD of mine, are the resulting MP4's in iTunes library protected from unauthorized access? Is my iTunes password still necessary?

Comment: When you export a original cd with iTunes, it does add some meta data to the file unique to your iTunes account, your iTunes password isn't stored in the file obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. iTunes does not apply any kind of DRM to songs imported from CDs, only to those bought from iTunes Store – and even that is 1) not being done anymore; 2) not dependent in any way on your password.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "unauthorized access", if your talking about applying DRM protection or... I don't think that if you import or "*rip*" media, that media becomes DRM protected...